# Long variable in C#, why does it return a negative value when it crosses the limits

Tags: c#, long-integer

I made an application to resolve the factorial and when I type a number longer than than 20 digits for a `long` variable , it returns a negative number.  I want to know why a `long` variable in C# returns a negative value when it crosses the limit? Is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: Please show calculation.

Comment: So you just assumed that variables can be infinitely large?

Comment: Watch the bits. What other outcome would you expect?

Comment: Why are you voting this guy down? Its basic and the english is poor, but the question is valid

Comment: The question is not valid, if he had searched he would have found tons of resources.

Comment: i only want to know why C# return me negative value? i mean i know the limits of long but i'm asking why a negative value, if it doesn't support the number why doesn't give me a error..instead a negative value.thanks for all.

Comment: sorry for my bad english,,, I'm spanish speaker.... XD

Comment: @AustinHenley - Actually I found it difficult to find a good explanation online. And it should be on SO to make this a dupe.

Comment: @HenkHolterman When searching on SO the first result was adequate, so it has already been duplicated (several times in fact). Searched on google, the first few pages of results seemed to answer the question.

Comment: @AustinHenley - then post a (few) link(s).

Comment: basically you haven't answered the main question yet, whay it retun a negative number?? "Why?"

Comment: The answer is there, if you look closely: MaxValue+1 overflows and the next number matches MinValue.

Answer (score 11):

This is quite normal behaviour, called overflow.

As a first step, turn it into an error with

```
checked
{
    // your calculations
}
```

And [this book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=euV7e2f-RzsC&pg=PA1172&lpg=PA1172&dq=c#%201s%20complement&source=bl&ots=LDxaW9FdNH&sig=bkD_NtQ0eOcLI0u5yQUE3f9FY44&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=LDlrULvRD4HZ0QWUzYDYDQ&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=c#%201s%20complement&f=false) has a thorough explanation with all the bits and bytes.

---

This might be of some help figuring it out:

```
static void Main2(string[] args)
{
    short s = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Dec: {0,6} Hex {0:X4}", s);
    s -= 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Dec: {0,6} Hex {0:X4}", s);

    s = short.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Dec: {0,6} Hex {0:X4}", s);
    s += 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Dec: {0,6} Hex {0:X4}", s);
    Console.WriteLine(s == short.MinValue);    // is MaxValue+1 == MinValue ?
}
```

It prints

```
Dec:      0 Hex 0000
Dec:     -1 Hex FFFF
Dec:  32767 Hex 7FFF
Dec: -32768 Hex 8000
True
```

Reading Hex char as bits:

```
0 = 0000
1 = 0001
7 = 0111
8 = 1000
F = 1111
```

You can see that the most significant (left-most) bit is used as the `+/-` sign.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone has already mentioned why it turns negative, so I'll just tell you how you can change your factorial function. Use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (assuming you are using .NET 4.0).

```
static BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger bigInt) {
    if (bigInt == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (bigInt == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return bigInt * Factorial(bigInt - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Holds signed 64-bit (8-byte) integers ranging in value from
>   -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (9.2...E+18).

```
20! = 2.432902e+18
21! = 5.1090942e+19
```

As you can see, 21! is well over hte max on `long`.

Some better links for C# data types:

[Integral Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
[Floating-Point Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ahet949%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

If you're planning on computing factorials over 20!, you'll need to step up to a Floating-Point type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 21! is great than the [long limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx), but 20! is not. Thus it is overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

All of the numeric types in c# support a max function so [Long.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) will tell you the limit.  As for why it goes negative that has to do with setting the high order bit of a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) encoded number

Answer (score 1):

It is called [arithmetic overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow).

A 4-bit example:

```
 1101
+0101
-----
10010
```

As you can see, the correct answer would require 5-bits but how do we store this in 4-bits?! We can't correctly, overflow must occur.

To answer your direct question, your value becomes negative because it is signed so when it overflows it wraps around to the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

The `long` data type has an [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Basically what you are telling us is not the entire story. This upper long limit is `9.223372037x10^18` and the factorial of 20 is `2.432902008x10^18` less than the upper limit for `long`.

I would post some code up so we can look at what actually is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that kind of overflow, consider using [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). To use it, your C# project needs to include a reference to the .NET assembly `System.Numerics.dll`. And your code file should include

```
using System.Numerics;
```

in the top.